# Cannot resolve "Undefined control sequence" in swaeve (using \Sexpr{})

Tags: sweave, rstudio

I have troubles finding a solution for a basic error I get.

I was trying to use a .Rnw document as it is by default created in RStudio to report some results. I have to admit that I am new to Sweave. However, I used `\Sexpr{}`in order to represent some numbers defined in a chunk. It did not work and returned the error  "Undefined control sequence". So I tried the example given in the official introduction:

```
    <<echo=FALSE>>=
x <- 2
y <- 3
(z <- x + y)
@
```

However, I get the same error when using `$z=\Sexpr{z}$` ("Undefined control sequence")

I assume something fundamentally is wrong with my file, but I can't figure out what. Here my whole document:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[noae]{Sweave}
\usepackage{graphicx, verbatim}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in} 
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in} 
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}



\begin{center}
\textbf{Data}
\end {center}

\section*{Questionnaires}

\subsection*{Stress}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
x <- 2
y <- 3
(z <- x + y)
@
Defining $z$ as above we get $z=\Sexpr{z}$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I typically use knitr but I changed my RStudio settings to use Sweave to try this out.  It worked fine for me.

Comment: @Dason basically I just used the description from [link] (http://www.math.montana.edu/~jimrc/classes/Rseminar/SweaveIntro.html) I have no clue whats wrong

Comment: Then forget about this and follow the advice given on that page "If you're brand new to Sweave, I recommend that you instead use knitr instead. It requires R version 2.14 or better, but it has some advantages, and you need either it or Sweave, not both."